# Finding the MLE if the second derivative is not less than 0

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, order-statistics

Let $X_1,\,X_2,\,X_3,\ldots ,X_n$ represents a random sample from each of the distributions.

I have a certain function :

$$f(x;\theta)=\begin{cases}e^{\theta-x}& x\geq\theta \\ 0 & x<\theta\end{cases}$$

for $\theta\in(-\infty,\infty)$.

Finding the MLE!

My answer is the following :

$$\begin{align}
L(\theta;\,x_i)&=e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta)}\\
\ln{L(\theta;\,x_i)}&=-\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta)\\
\ln{L(\theta;\,x_i)}&=n\theta-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
D_\theta\ln{L(\theta;\,x_i)}&=n>0\\
D_{\theta\theta}\ln{L(\theta;\,x_i)}&=0
\end{align}
$$

But i'm having trouble to find $\hat \theta$

My professor said that we must use ordered statistics when we meet this case. I mean, when the second derivative is zero or greater than zero.

But how to use ordered statistics for finding the estimator?

Comment: But it might not be a pdf.. it might be pmf. My teacher said, that f(x) is pdf or pmf. And it's true cz for example, we can find the estimator from poisson dist. (pmf). Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Just for information, i took this question from Introduction to Mathematical Statistics 6th edition sect. 6 number 3 (if i'm not wrong)

Comment: You did not write the definition of the function correctly. I'm updating your post.

Comment: Ok thanks for the correction.

Comment: Differentiation is not the only way of searching for MLE. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651553/showing-that-the-mle-doesnt-exist-for-e-theta-x, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019525/mle-of-delta-for-the-distribution-fx-e-delta-x-for-x-geq-delta?noredirect=1&lq=1. This has been asked numerous times here, so do search the site.

Comment: I know. It's actually correct. Thanks for the link. That link gives me an answer that the way for finding mle is use ordered statistics if it failed to obtain second derivative is less than zero.

Comment: @user516076 Forget differentiation for a moment and focus on the nature of the likelihood as a function of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second derivative is unnecessary.

Comment: It's needed. Bcz we must to know and ensure that the second derivative is less than zero. From that, we allowed to set the first derivative is equal to zero. But if the second derivative isn't LT zero, we can't.

Comment: @user516076 Forget second derivative, even first derivative is unnecessary here. Notably $\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln L(\theta)$ (your $L(\theta)$ is not completely correct) does not exist at $\theta=\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

Comment: Yes.. on my last comment below i've said that it use ordered statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

- The likelihood is zero if any of the $x_i$s is less than $\theta$
- The likelihood is a positive and increasing function of $\theta$ (you have shown it has a positive first derivative), provided that $\theta$ is less than or equal to all the $x_i$s
- So the likelihood is maximised when $\theta$ is ...