# $MLE$ of $\theta$ when $X_1 , X_2 , ..., X_n$ is a sample with pdf $f(x, \theta) = e^{\theta - x}; x \ge \theta$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

How can we find the $MLE$ of $\theta$ when $X_1 , X_2 , ..., X_n$ is a sample with pdf $f(x, \theta) = e^{\theta - x}; x \ge \theta$ ?

$L(\theta) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} e^{\theta - x_{i}}$

$L(\theta) = e^{n\theta}e^{-\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i}$

$\ln(L(\theta)) = n\theta - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i$

Then I have to solve $\frac{\partial\ln(L(\theta))}{\partial\theta} = 0$. But:

$\frac{\partial\ln(L(\theta))}{\partial\theta} = n$.

I'm stuck :/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289542/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Show and use that the likelihood function is of the form
$$
L(\theta)=\mathrm{e}^{\theta n}\mathrm{e}^{-\sum x_i}\mathbf{1}_{\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\geq \theta}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added where I'm stuck in the question.

Comment: Your likelihood function is incorrect as you're missing an indicator function. The pdf is $\mathrm{e}^{\theta-x}\mathbf{1}_{x\geq \theta}$ not $\mathrm{e}^{\theta -x}$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation, what does $\mathbf{1}_{x \ge \theta}$ mean?

Comment: $\mathbf{1}_{x\geq \theta}$ is $1$ when $x\geq \theta$ and $0$ when $x<\theta$. In your calculations you forget to put $f(x,\theta)=0$ when $x<\theta$.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But I have absolutely no idea about how to express $\theta$'s $MLE$ then :/

Comment: The factor $\mathrm{e}^{-\sum x_i}$ doesn't depend on $\theta$, so you have to maximize $\mathrm{e}^{\theta n}$ under the constraint that $\theta\leq \min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Can you do this?

Comment: $\theta = \text{min}(x_1, ..., x_n)$ ?

Comment: Indeed @toogy. ${}$