# Getting n=0 after differentiating the log MLE

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to get the MLE for $\theta$ for the following CDF:
$$f_{\theta}=e^{-(x-\theta)}, x>\theta$$

This is what I did:
$$L(\theta|X)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}e^{-(x_{i}-\theta)}$$
$$L(\theta|X)=e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\theta)}$$
$$logL(\theta|X)=-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\theta)$$
$$logL(\theta|X)=-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i})+n\theta$$

After $d/d\theta$, I got $n=0$:
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}logL(\theta|X)=0$$
$$n=0$$

What is wrong with my computation?

Comment: The maximum likelihood does not have to be where the derivative of the (log-)likelihood is $0$.  It can be at one end of the interval

Comment: Your calculations do not take account the question saying $x > \theta$ in the density (the CDF is in fact $F_\theta(x)=1-e^{-(x-\theta)}$ when $x \ge \theta$ and $=0$ when $x \le \theta$)

Comment: @Henry, got it! Thank you

Comment: [How do I find the MLE of $\theta$ when x is dependent on $\theta$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289542/how-do-i-find-the-mle-of-theta-when-x-is-dependent-on-theta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the pdf rather than CDF.

We want to maximize $-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i + n\theta$ subject to $x_i \ge \theta$.

We want $\theta$ to be as large as possible but it has to be smaller than all the $x_i$. Hence $\theta = \min_i x_i$.